# Modal taking click priority over Reactour component in react project

Tags: reactjs, class, next.js, modal-dialog

Problem: I have a React application where I'm using the Reactour library (https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/reactour) to provide a guided tour for users. However, I'm facing an issue where a modal component is taking click priority over the Reactour component. This means that when the modal is open, I'm unable to interact with the Reactour elements.

[image]

Code Snippets:

Reactour Configuration:

```
<TourProvider steps={[]}
      styles={{
        popover: (base) => ({
          ...base,
          '--reactour-accent': '#ef5a3d',
          borderRadius: radius,
          zIndex: 20000
        }),
        maskArea: (base) => ({ 
          ...base, 
          rx: radius }),
        maskWrapper: (base) => ({ 
          ...base, 
          color: '#57697E',
          zIndex: 20000 }),
        controls: (base) => ({ 
          ...base, 
          marginTop: 50 }),
        close: (base) => ({ 
          ...base, 
          right: 8, 
          left: 'auto', 
          top: 8 }),
        arrow: base => ({
          ...base,
          zIndex: 22000
        }),
      }}
      showBadge= {false}
      showDots= {false}
      scrollSmooth={true}
      beforeClose={() => console.log("Tour finished or closed")}>
```

Modal Component:

```
return (
    <>
      <div className={"modal-container w-[1050px] h-[600px]"} style={{ zIndex: 10 }}>
        <div className="mt-3 sm:mt-5">
          <div>
            <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
              <div className="flex flex-1 flex-row gap-4">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  id="name"
                  className="block h-[48px] uppercase text-center bg-sky-500 rounded border-0 p-0 text-white focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                  defaultValue={modalManager?.data?.character?.name}
                  onChange={(event) =>
                    handleInputChange({
                      name: "name",
                      value: event.target.value
                    })
                  }
                />
```

Expected Behavior: I expect the Reactour component to receive click events even when the modal is open. The Reactour component should remain interactive and allow users to continue the tour.

Attempts Made:

I have checked the rendering order of components and ensured that the Reactour component is rendered after the modal component.
I have reviewed the z-index values of the modal and Reactour components, ensuring that the modal has a lower z-index value than reactour.
Additional Information:

React version: 18.2.0
Reactour version: @reactour/popover": "^1.1.1"
@reactour/tour": "^3.6.1"
Browser and version: Chrome and Firefox

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!